# Issue in Implementing ERC721 Interface to my Project

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I am trying to used ERC721 Interface but I got the Error in bytes parameter

```
 TypeError: Data location must be "calldata" for parameter in external function, but none was given.
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;
                                                                            ^--------^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.2 (core: 5.0.2)
Node v10.14.1


    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes  data) external payable;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, you need to specify `calldata` as the location for the parameter `data`:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes calldata data) external payable;
```